# Diabetes risk: Is eating dried dates more dangerous than eating cake?

Tags: nutrition, diabetes, sugar

I checked some random packages of various cakes and cookies in the supermarket. The sugar content per 100g of product went like 18g, 22g, 32g, or 38g.

Meanwhile, on the package of dried dates the sugar amount was 65 g per 100g of product.

I realize that dried dates have many beneficial vitamins and minerals, but from the point of view of diabetes risk, is it more dangerous to eat dried dates (or other fruits) than cookies and cakes?

As I understand from [this thread](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/116/why-is-natural-sugar-healthier-than-refined-sugar), refined sugar and natural sugar are equally unhealthy in excessive amounts. So, if i eat 100g of cake, it will be healthier than eating 100g of dried dates, yes?